# Web Deployment Task Failed: Unicode keyword not suported

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, web-deployment

I'm now trying to build deployment package for my Visual Studio 2010 ASP.NET Project. But, I'm getting an error that I cannot resolve:

```
Error   1   Web deployment task failed.(Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aba1437;Password=aba1437eg;Unicode=True' cannot be created.)

Object of type 'dbFullSql' and path 'Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aba1437;Password=aba1437eg;Unicode=True' cannot be created.
The value 'Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aba1437;Password=aba1437eg;Unicode=True' is not a valid connection string or an absolute path.
Keyword not supported: 'unicode'.       0   0   Titanic
```

The connection string looks in the following way:

```
Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=aba1437;Password=***********;Unicode=True
```

I would really appreciate any suggestions because I did not found any useful tips to resolve the  problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the ending semicolon.

```
Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;
User ID=aba1437;Password=***********;Unicode=True;
```

Comment: I though about it. But this connection string is copied from the properties window of the database connection. And It has not ending semicolon there: (Sorry, no rep for uploading pictures)
http://c2n.me/3uLqXpu

Comment: Ah okay.  I will leave my answer up so that other people won't think that it is the correct solution.